# PJSIP sample code app_perror was not declared in the scope

Tags: c++, c, compilation, pjsip

I am trying to get the [sample code](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/page_pjsip_sample_simple_ua_c.htm) of PJSIP to work but during compilation i get the error:

```
MXC061:~$ g++ -I /usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -o hello gst.cpp `pkg-config 
--cflags --libs libpjproject`
error: ‘app_perror’ was not declared in this scope
app_perror(THIS_FILE, "Unable to start UDP transport", status);
```

i know that i should somehow include the library directory but i don't even know which header **app_perror()** belongs to.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably this error comes from a copy/paste problem from another sample file. I mean, `app_perror` is defined on every sample file to show possible errors in different ways depending on test running, this is, for solving your error, you would need to add its definition, initially, at the beginning, for example, before `logging_on_rx_msg`:

```
static void app_perror(const char *sender, const char *title, pj_status_t status)
{
    char errmsg[PJ_ERR_MSG_SIZE];

    pj_strerror(status, errmsg, sizeof(errmsg));
    PJ_LOG(1,(sender, "%s: %s", title, errmsg));
}
```